# Converting data from serial/usb using PySerial

Tags: python

I have a UBlox receiver connected to my computer and I am trying to read it using PySerial however I am new to python and was hoping to get some clarification/help on understanding the data.

My code looks like:

```
import serial
# open the connection port
connection = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
# open a file to print the data. I am doing this to make
# sure it is working
file1 = open('output_file', 'wb+')
# All messages from ublox receivers end with a carriage return
# and a newline 
msg = connection.readline()
# print the message to the file
print >> file1, msg
```

What I get in the file, and when I print the 'type' of msg it is a list:

['\xb5b\x01\x064\x00\xe0\x88\x96#\xd3\xb9\xff\xffX\x07\x03\xdd6\xc31\xf6\xfd)\x18\xea\xe6\x8fd\x1d\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x02\x0f\x16\xa2\x02\x00\x9c\xeb\xb5b\x01\x07\\x00\xe0\x88\x96#\xe0\x07\x01\x17\x15237\x04\x00\x00\x00\xd6\xb9\xff\xff\x03\x01\n']

["\x1a\x0c\x04\x19'y\x00$\xf7\xff\xff\x1a\x1d\x04\x01\x00\x007\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x1f\x0c\x01\x00+:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01 \r\x07&-\x9f\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\x17\xc1\x0c\x04\x16\n"]

In order to interpret/decode the ublox messages have two format types. Some of the messages are in NMEA format(basically comma delimited)

```
$MSG, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Where the other messages are straight hexidecimal, where each byte or set of bytes represent some information

```
[AA BB CC DD EE]
```

So my question is: is there a way I can interpret/convert the data from serial connection to a readable or more usable format so I can actually work with the messages. Like I said, I am new to python and more used to C++ style strings or array of characters

`

Comment: it is string (or array of characters or bytes). You can get element on position `pos` by `msg[pos]` or `msg[0][pos]`.  `\x01` means char/byte with hex code `01`

Comment: Note that [it's strongly advised to use a timeout with `readline` to avoid infinite waits](https://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline).

Answer (score 0):

A typical [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Overview_of_process) task. In this case, it'll probably be the simplest to make tokenization two-stage:

1. read the data until you run into a message boundary (you didn't give enough info on how to recognize it)
2. split the read message into its meaningful parts

   - for type 1, it's likely [`re.split(", *",text)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)
   - for type 2, none needed
3. display the parts however you want

---

Regarding why `serial.Serial.readline` returns a list. I consulted the sources - `serial.Serial` delegates `readline` to [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html?highlight=io.iobase#io.IOBase), and [its source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_io/iobase.c#l445) indeed shows that it should return a `bytestring`.

So, the function might be overridden in your code by something. E.g. what do `print connection.readline` and `print serial.Serial.readline` show?

Comment: Could you be more specific on how he is supposed to split the string. I am also quite curious. "\x" is not allowed as a delimiter.  @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: When I take msg[0] for example, I just end up getting the whole message. It appears msg is a list, with the first element being the whole message but I am working on whether that is true. When i take msg[1] it gives me an out of range error

Comment: I've no idea why it's a list. I'll consult the source now. This isn't much of a problem and not the primary focus of your question (as it's now) anyway.